# Unable to access WordPress server locally running using vagrant

Tags: local-installation, linux, vagrant

Until recently I have been using Debian on my desktop, however I've decided to migrate to arch. I develop a WordPress website for someone, and I copied the `vagrant-local` folder containing the vagrant virtual-box containing WordPress to my arch computer. I installed virtual-box, vagrant and mod-probed the kernel drivers and made vagrant successfully run.

However I am not able to open the `local.wordpress.dev` url on my arch computer, which should give me access to the local WordPress server.

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1     localhost.localdomain   localhost
192.168.50.4 vvv.dev local.wordpress.dev local.wordpress-trunk.dev src.wordpress-develop.dev build.wordpress-develop.dev
$ vagrant status
Current machine states:

default                   running (virtualbox)

The VM is running. To stop this VM, you can run `vagrant halt` to
shut it down forcefully, or you can run `vagrant suspend` to simply
suspend the virtual machine. In either case, to restart it again,
simply run `vagrant up`.

$ ping local.wordpress.dev -c 1
PING vvv.dev (192.168.50.4) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- vvv.dev ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

$ ping 192.168.50.4 -c 1
PING 192.168.50.4 (192.168.50.4) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.50.4 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?   Or do you still need help?

Comment: It has been resolved, I think I just destroyed the vagrant box and made a new one.